# Dividing div to 2 columns

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have seen some solutions to this problem but when I add inside the divs an angular2 component, it doesn't work.

**Here is what I got so far:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="categoriesContainer">
    <categories (onCategoryChanged)="categoryChanged($event)"></categories>
  </div>
  <div id="products-container">
    <product-details *ngFor="let product of products$ | async" id="prodcut"
                     [product]="product"
                     [canAddProductToCart]="canAddToCart(product.$key) | async"
                     (onAddToCart)="addToCart($event)"></product-details>
    <button md-button
            *ngIf="!showCreateProductComponent"
            id="create-product-button"
            [disabled]="disableCreateProductButton$ |async"
            (click)="showCreateProductComponent=true">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </button>
    <create-product id="create-product"
                    (onCencel)="showCreateProductComponent=false"
                    (onCreateProduct)="onCreateProduct($event)"
                    *ngIf="showCreateProductComponent"></create-product>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
//spliting the div to 2 columns
#container
{
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px
}
#categoriesContainer
{
  width: 15%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
#products-container
{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 85%;
  border-color: red;
}

//for the angular2 compoennts
#prodcut
{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#create-product
{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#create-product-button
{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**Here is what I want:** (the cards will be only in the red squer.)

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How to fix this and why its working great when I remove the angular2 components and replace them with some simple html text?
2. Can I summerise this code without effecting anything:

   ```
   <div id="categoriesContainer"
      style="width: 15%;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: blue;float: left">
   <categories (onCategoryChanged)="categoryChanged($event)"></categories>
   ```

to:

```
<categories id="categoriesContainer"
               style="width: 15%;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: blue;float: left"
 (onCategoryChanged)="categoryChanged($event)"></categories>
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simple using `flexbox`

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#left, #right {
  padding: 16px;
}

#left {
  width: 15%;
  background: red;
}

#right {
  width: 85%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">left</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

#### Simple using `float`s and `box-sizing`

<sub>You might want to use also a [`.clearfix` class](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) here on the parent element</sub>

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

#left, #right {
  float: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

#left {
  width: 15%;
  background: red;
}

#right {
  width: 85%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">left</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

#### Using `display:table` (cross-browser)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
} 

#left, #right {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 16px;
}

#left {
  width: 15%;
  background: red;
}

#right {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">left</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `float:left` for children node and `clear:both, content: ''` for the parent node?

What I mean is that you miss a `float:left` for the `#products-container`

```
<div class="container clearfix"> 
  <div id="categoriesContainer" style="float:left" ></div>
  <div id="products-container" style="float:left" ></div>
</div>
```

About the clearfix class, you can refer to Bootstrap [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/clearfix/).

Comment: Math bro, math. 15% + 85% + paddings + borders != 100%